# Need help inputting properties into object variable

Tags: javascript, object, properties, key

I want to make it so in the input box, when it is entered, the values are assigned to properties in the object variable. For example: If for the weight you input 180, the value of 180 is assigned to the weight. Also not sure how to display the key and the values. Right now I have it so it's in the console.

My current code is

```js
var basketballplayers = {
  weight: "",
  height: "",
  wins: "",
  losses: "",
};

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let pikachu = this.value;
    console.log(pikachu);
    document.getElementById("charzard").innerHTML = pikachu;
  }
});

document.getElementById('number1').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let pikachu1 = this.value;
    console.log(pikachu1);
    document.getElementById("charzard1").innerHTML = pikachu1;

  }
});

document.getElementById('number2').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let pikachu2 = this.value;
    console.log(pikachu2);
    document.getElementById("charzard2").innerHTML = pikachu2;

  }
});

document.getElementById('number3').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    let pikachu3 = this.value;
    console.log(pikachu3);
    document.getElementById("charzard3").innerHTML = pikachu3;

  }
});









for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(basketballplayers)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

```html
<h1>Basketball Players</h1>
<p id="zip"></p>

<p>Weight:</p><input type="number" id="number" />
<p id="charzard"></p>
<p>Height:</p><input type="number" id="number1" />
<p id="charzard1"></p>
<p>Wins:</p><input type="number" id="number2" />
<p id="charzard2"></p>
<p>Losses:</p><input type="number" id="number3" />
<p id="charzard3"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this for each input. eg: To assign value of input weight to object property

```
basketballplayers.weight = pikachu
```

Here's for each input feild

```
var basketballplayers = {
    weight: "",
    height: "",
    wins: "",
    losses: "",
};

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          let pikachu = this.value;
          console.log(pikachu);
          basketballplayers.weight = pikachu;
          document.getElementById("charzard").innerHTML = pikachu;
      }
});

document.getElementById('number1').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        let pikachu1 = this.value;
        console.log(pikachu1);
        basketballplayers.height = pikachu1;
        document.getElementById("charzard1").innerHTML = pikachu1;
    }
});

document.getElementById('number2').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
         let pikachu2 = this.value;
         console.log(pikachu2);
         basketballplayers.wins = pikachu2;
         document.getElementById("charzard2").innerHTML = pikachu2;
    }
});

document.getElementById('number3').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        let pikachu3 = this.value;
        console.log(pikachu3);
        basketballplayers.Losses = pikachu3;
        document.getElementById("charzard3").innerHTML = pikachu3;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

after assigning values to pikachu1,2,3.
you can modify the object immediately.

```
basketballplayers = {...basketballplayers, weight: pikachu}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update **basketballplayers** object instead paragraph's innerHTML:

```js
var basketballplayers = {
  weight: "",
  height: "",
  wins: "",
  losses: "",
};

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    basketballplayers.weight = this.value;
    console.log(basketballplayers);
  }
});

document.getElementById('number1').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    basketballplayers.height = this.value;
    console.log(basketballplayers);
  }
});

document.getElementById('number2').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    basketballplayers.wins = this.value;
    console.log(basketballplayers);
  }
});

document.getElementById('number3').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    basketballplayers.losses = this.value;
    console.log(basketballplayers);
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>Basketball Players</h1>
<p id="zip"></p>

<p>Weight:</p><input type="number" id="number" />
<p id="charzard"></p>
<p>Height:</p><input type="number" id="number1" />
<p id="charzard1"></p>
<p>Wins:</p><input type="number" id="number2" />
<p id="charzard2"></p>
<p>Losses:</p><input type="number" id="number3" />
<p id="charzard3"></p>
```